# At least 2 letters in regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

How can I enforce a minimum of 2 letters in the following regex?

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.\+]+$/`

For the moment I'm stripping out everything that is not a letter and counting the result with `strlen` to achieve what I need.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.\+]{2,}$/`

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9][2,]$/. if letters are in mind. not special characters

Comment: @cmorrissey That will allow two underscores.

Comment: @Barmar ah yeah, I was assuming that he meant anything in his regex as a "letter" I would ask the OP to clarify if he means "letter" or "character"

Comment: If you need to find out if a string has 2 letters at least, you can do this /[a-zA-Z]{2,}/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]*(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]*){2,}$`

Expanded:

```
 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]* 
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]* 
 ){2,}
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following if letters mean anything in the set you are using:

```
(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]{2,}$/     //here you can remove escape 
                             //characters inside character set
```

You can use the following if letters mean `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_-.+]+$/
```

Explanation:

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])` look ahead for atleast two letters

Comment: That will allow `..` or `++`, which don't have any letters.